# Are the permutations of the Group Caley table rows form the same Group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

For Example :-
Z/Z4

0 1 2 3 -> ()
1 2 3 0 -> (0, 1, 2, 3)
2 3 0 1 -> (0, 2)(1, 3)
3 0 1 2 -> (0, 3, 2, 1)

The above Permutations under permutation combination operation also form the same group.

Example of Nonabelian Group:-
Group D_3

0  1  2  3  4  5 -> ()
1  2  0  4  5  3 -> (0 ,1 ,2)(3 ,4 ,5)
2  0  1  5  3  4 -> (0 ,2 ,1)(3 ,5 ,4)
3  5  4  0  2  1 -> (0 ,3)(1 ,5)(2 ,4)
4  3  5  1  0  2 -> (0 ,4)(1 ,3)(2 ,5)
5  4  3  2  1  0 -> (0 ,5)(1 ,4)(2 ,3)

The above Permutations under permutation combination operation also form the same group.

I haven't found counter example yet hence I'm wondering if Is this is true for all Groups? and can this relation be proven?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially Cayley's theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, given a group $G=\{g_1,\ldots,g_n\}$, consider the left multiplications $l_{g_i}:G\rightarrow G: g\mapsto g_ig$. The left multiplications correspond to the rows in the group table.

The set of left multiplications $L=\{l_{g_1},\ldots,l_{g_n}\}$ forms a subgroup of the symmetric group $S_G=\{f\mid f:G\rightarrow G\mbox{ bij.}\}$, since $l_{g}l_h=l_{gh}$ and $l_g^{-1}=l_{g^{-1}}$.

Thus the left multiplications are permutations of the set $G$ and so have a representation in cycle form.

Have a look into Cayley's theorem.